# How to redirect random port to a closed port

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, http, tunnel

As the title might suggest, i'm trying to redirect a port (ex: 64400) to a closed port (ex: 22).

What i would like to know is if there is any possibility to do this directly form my router, or is my only option to do this from the server itself ?

I would like to keep port 22 on my SSH config, but i would want to use a different OPENED port to connect to it.
So does anyone know how this can be done ? I've looked on Google on a lot of forums but i didn't find anything that helps me.

Comment: A random port mapped to 22/SSH? VERY bad idea. Add information as why you'd like to do that and on what platforms, etc.?

Comment: Well i was thinking that most attackers would do a port scan before doing anything, so i was thinking that if i change the SSH port to another (less used) one, security would be a bit better. This is on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian OS.

Comment: Sounds like [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). I read it like you wanted to point ALL random ports to 22/SSH. In your case: there should be tons of information for that, but I'll add an answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [port forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) your *random* (meaning fixed port other than 22) port to 22 on your server. Most routers can do that. You don't have to change anything on your RaspPi SSH Server. That info should get you going.

It's going to look like this:

> internet --ssh--> port 2222 -> router --port 2222 forwarded to 22-->
>   RaspPi SSH server

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if i wanted to port forward 80 for example ? I would like to visit my http://domain.com with the port 80 closed, but another port would automatically forword that to port 80 somehow and serve me the right content. Would this be possible ?

Comment: I think you're mixing up some terms in general. A *closed* port will never answer to anything, it's closed. Accessible from the internet / outside is something different. You can block (via iptables or whatever) connections to ports, even if the port is *open*. Maybe you should describe what you want in detail.